# org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001456: Argument resolvedBean must not be null

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, cdi, wildfly, entitylisteners

Injecting EJBs into entity listeners is available, since JPA 2.1. WildFly 9.0.2 final however, fails with the following exception.

```
15:41:12,125 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 149) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."Test.ear/Test-ejb.jar#Test-ejbPU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."Test.ear/Test-ejb.jar#Test-ejbPU": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Test-ejbPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:665)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Test-ejbPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:877)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:805)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001456: Argument resolvedBean must not be null
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Preconditions.checkArgumentNotNull(Preconditions.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:813)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:375)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:386)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.BeanManagerListenerFactory$BeanMetaData.<init>(BeanManagerListenerFactory.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.BeanManagerListenerFactory$BeanMetaData.<init>(BeanManagerListenerFactory.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.BeanManagerListenerFactory.buildListener(BeanManagerListenerFactory.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.LegacyCallbackProcessor.resolveCallbacks(LegacyCallbackProcessor.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.LegacyCallbackProcessor.processCallbacksForEntity(LegacyCallbackProcessor.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator.integrate(JpaIntegrator.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
    ... 9 more

15:41:12,125 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"Test.ear/Test-ejb.jar#Test-ejbPU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"Test.ear/Test-ejb.jar#Test-ejbPU\": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Test-ejbPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Test-ejbPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001456: Argument resolvedBean must not be null"}}
```

Asking this question only because I read somewhere that injecting EJBs and/or CDI events into entity listeners is available since WildFly 8.2. Therefore, I feel I go wrong somewhere.

Unlike GlassFish where it succeeds (at least on GlassFish 4.1), does WildFly requires us to take some extra care about injecting EJBs and/or CDI events into entity listeners?

---

I have tested this on a completely blank enterprise application having nothing other than a blank session bean (stateless) which is to be injected into an entity listener and a few JPA entities.

The listener :

```
public class ProductListener {

    @Inject
    private TestService service;

    @PostPersist
    public void postPersist() {

    }
}
```

The EJB is left completely blank :

```
@Stateless
public class TestBean implements TestService {

}
```

The exception vanishes, if the injection point (`TestService`) is removed.

Designating the listener with `@ApplicationScoped` or `@Singleton` does not help either (which in turn should not be needed in reality).

The Hibernate version is 5.0.5 final and the Weld version is 2.2.16.

---

**Update 1 :**

Updated to Hibernate 5.0.6 final.

**Update 2 :**

The issue persists in **WildFly 10.0.0 final** released on Friday, January 29, 2016 having Hibernate 5.0.7 final / Weld 2.3 final.

**Update 3 :**

According to the [issue status](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8706), this has been fixed in Hibernate 5.1.0 final and it should have worked accordingly in WildFly 10.0.0 final but it still fails to work with the same exception - no improvement.

Comment: It's likely a difference in how eclipselink deals with it vs hibernate.  Can you share your `TestService` implementation?

Comment: The implementation of `TestService` is `TestBean` which is entirely left blank exactly as shown in the question (no method, nothing else inside it). The application itself is a blank project having only a single empty stateless session bean (`TestService`), a single entity listener and a few entities, nothing more. The exception is thrown, when the application is attempted to be deployed.

Comment: Ok, so your error has nothing to do with these beans.  The exception mentions a resource injection.  My inclination is that your bean has a circular reference back to the persistence context, which may lead to this problem but without more code behind it I can't tell for sure.

Comment: When may a bean have a "circular reference"? I did not twist anything. (As said above, the application contains nothing other than a session bean, an entity listener and a few entities with no special additional configurations. The web module is completely left untouched).

Comment: I think it is a known issue https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8706 & https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2387

Comment: Did you register entity listeners by `@EntityListeners` on the `@Entity` class, or by `<entity-listeners>` in `persistence-xml`? Annotation way has always worked for us, but never tried XML way.

Comment: @BalusC : They have been registered in `orm.xml` which works perfectly fine in GlassFish 4.1 but I have just tried using `@EntityListeners(Listener.class)` in a sendbox project (which had already been created before this question was asked). It failed with the same exception.

Comment: Do you have a WAR or EAR(EJB+WAR) project? In case of EAR, entities and entity listeners should go in EJB.

Comment: @BalusC : It is EAR. The only entity listener along with entities is placed in the EJB module of the sendbox project.

Comment: @BalusC : The sendbox project gets deployed when a `true` value is given to `<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>`. It was set to `false` before which is required in the real project, since entity classes have been placed in a class library in that project to avoid duplication which results in `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.Entity cannot be cast to com.example.Entity`.

Comment: Have you tried injecting the SLSB with @EJB annotation instead of @Inject? Works for me on Wildfly 10.0.0.Final... (the listener is registered in `orm.xml`)

Comment: @TomaszKnyziak : Excluding EJBs, CDI events are CDI artifacts, hence injecting them into entity listeners requires `@Inject` compulsorily. Thus, replacing `@Inject` with `@EJB` to inject EJBs into entity listener is still not a rescue as CDI events still require `@Inject` though that part is not covered in the question.

Comment: @Tiny - not arguing about all-purpose CDI injection into Entity Listeners, Wildfly indeed still fails that. I just meant to point out that in this particular case, `@EJB` injection doest the trick.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @Franck, it is a bug and was eventually fixed last year in version 11 only (wildfly) (and so also in EAP 7.1). We use EAP 7.0 (wildfly 10) and same issue and we can't upgrade. As workaround we use now the suggestion of @Tiny, moving our functionality to an EJB and using `@EJB` iso `@Inject`.

Credits to all users of this topic, just wanted to consolidate this in an answer for later reference.